# Left-Child Right-Sibling move a sibling to a child node?

Tags: c++, tree, binary-tree

I have for example a Left-Child Right-Sibling tree:
[image]

If for example, I want to make E (including its child nodes E,K,L,P,Q) a child to H node. So H will contain N,O, E(and its children)
I intend to add the children to the parent node, then delete the old nodes but then there are new parent-children pairs. What is the shortest way for this?

Here's some code to reproduce:

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h> 
#include<iostream>
using namespace std; 

struct Node 
{ 
    string data; 
    struct Node *next; 
    struct Node *child; 
}; 

// Creating new Node 
Node* newNode(string data) 
{ 
    Node *newNode = new Node; 
    newNode->next = newNode->child = NULL; 
    newNode->data = data; 
    return newNode; 
} 

// Adds a sibling to a list with starting with n 
Node *addSibling(Node *n, string data) 
{ 
    if (n == NULL) 
        return NULL; 

    while (n->next) 
        n = n->next; 

    return (n->next = newNode(data)); 
} 

// Add child Node to a Node 
Node *addChild(Node * n, string data) 
{ 
    if (n == NULL) 
        return NULL; 

    // Check if child list is not empty. 
    if (n->child) 
        return addSibling(n->child, data); 
    else
        return (n->child = newNode(data)); 
} 

// Traverses tree in level order 
void traverseTree(Node * root) 
{ 
    if (root == NULL) 
        return; 

    while (root) 
    { 
        cout << " " << root->data; 
        if (root->child) 
            traverseTree(root->child); 
        root = root->next; 
    } 
} 

//Driver code 

int main() 
{ 

    Node *root = newNode("A"); 
    Node *nB  = addChild(root, "B"); 
    Node *nC  = addChild(root, "C"); 
    Node *nD  = addChild(root, "D"); 
    Node *nE  = addChild(root, "E"); 
    Node *nF  = addChild(root, "F"); 
    Node *nG  = addChild(root, "G"); 
    Node *nH  = addChild(nB, "H"); 
    Node *nI  = addChild(nB, "I"); 
    Node *nJ  = addChild(nB, "J"); 
    Node *nK  = addChild(nE, "K"); 
    Node *nL  = addChild(nE, "L");
    Node *nM  = addChild(nG, "M"); 
    Node *nN  = addChild(nH, "N"); 
    Node *nO  = addChild(nH, "O");
    Node *nP  = addChild(nK, "P"); 
    Node *nQ  = addChild(nL, "Q");
    traverseTree(root); 
    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: "I want to move E (including its child nodes E,K,L,P,Q) to H node." Do you want to replace H with E, make E a child of H, or make E a sibling of H?

Comment: I want to make E a child of H, so H will contain N,O and E. will correct that to my question

Comment: What's your interface for this operation? Function name and input?

Comment: @John not sure if I understand, you can check the code on how to implement the tree on the right. But now I need to move the nodes

Comment: Sorry, I assumed you'd want to implement a function to do this operation? Something like, `moveNode(string child, string parent)` or something like that.

Comment: @John I think it could be ```moveNode(Node* child, Node* parent)```

Comment: Please make a representation (I recommend some ASCII art in code formatting) of the tree you want as a result. I understand that you want the siblings of e (i.e. F and G) to become siblings of N and O  (i.e. also childs of H), along with E. But I am bot sure. A representation would help with that.

Comment: Yeah, but then whoever is using your interface needs pointers to the child and parent nodes. As a user I don't want to deal with nodes. I want to deal with values. If you want to use your prototype that's fine - it's valid - I'm just providing my suggestion.

Comment: Using your prototype, though: it looks like two operations. 1. Unlink the child from its current location (you need to find its current parent or upstream-sibling, and its downstream-sibling, and modify the former to point at the latter), then 2. If the new parent has no children, make this child the child of this parent; if the new parent does have a child, make this new child the child of the parent, and make the old child the downstream sibling of this child. Draw pictures. Lots and lots of pictures. With arrows.

Comment: @John How can I find the previous of node of E (in the right picture: node D)? I could start to traverse from the root A, but is there a more efficient way?

Comment: @Ha where did you get this code from?

Comment: @John From Geeksforgeeks: geeksforgeeks.org/creating-tree-left-child-right-sibling-representation/

Comment: Can you let us know what your homework assignment is? You may be overcomplicating it if you're reduced to pulling code off of random websites that you don't even understand. There's probably a simpler solution that aligns better with what you've learned in class so far.

Comment: But pending an answer to that question, no, there's no more efficient way to find out where a given node is in the tree besides an exhaustive search. Since the relationship between a node and its children, parents, and siblings is arbitrary (not related to the data in the node), you can't figure it out except by traversal from root.

Comment: So the user inserts some area names (for example District A, Country B, City C, etc) and then I need to make them into hierechial order (Country B -> City C -> District A). Because a parent can have more than 2 child, so it's a n-ary tree in this case.

Comment: But, since you're traversing to find node E, you might as well roll your search for H into the same search so you don't end up searching the tree twice.